# USB-C to Displayport cable or adapter

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, displayport

I'm using MacBook pro 2017 15 inch and i just got 3x DELL U2518D UltraSharp monitors to connect to my macbook pro.

What I actually need is best possible solution to connect this external monitors to my macbook pro. Should i use USB-C to DisplayPort adapter or should i go with USB-C to DisplayPort Cable?

What is difference? Is cable better? Or adapter?

Answer (score 4):

**Use a [Type C DisplayPort cable](http://radnex.us/Cable-Matters-USB-C-Display-Port-Cable-4K).**

The ports on your [MacBook Pro are Thunderbolt 3](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP756?locale=en_US) which is a multiplexing of multiple signals:

- PCIe
- USB 3.1
- DispayPort
- Power

Since it *natively* supports DisplayPort, you want a cable, not an adapter.

**Difference between cable and adapter**

- A cable is just an interconnect between a source and an end device using the same signaling
- An *adapter* creates a signal from one to another (from USB to DVI or HDMI)

In this case, a cable is "better" because it's not converting any signals.  Less conversion means better reliability.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, but should i be worried which cable i take? Manufacturer and stuff?

Comment: **Always** buy quality from a known reputable manufacturer.  I personally use the one linked.