# Dual 4k monitors limited to 30hz

Tags: display, thunderbolt

I am currently running two Dell U2720Q 4k monitors connected to my MacBook Pro (13', 2020) via thunderbolt 3 usb-c cables. Each monitor runs at 60hz when on its own but as soon as both are connected they switch to 30hz.

Both when connected alone and together no refresh rate options appear when holding down option and clicking on the scaled resolution option.

Comment: AFAIK running two 4K screens with 60Hz is an optional feature of Thunderbolt 3. Mandatory is only one 4K screen at 60 Hz. Not sure is the MacBook or the cable is the problem in your case.

Comment: How are the monitors connected? - Is it a direct cable from monitor A to the MBP, and another direct cable from monitor B to the MBP? - Or do you use any kind of dock, adapter, etc?  ... I'm running 2 4k monitors at 60 Hz from my MBP right now, so it should be possible to get working.

Comment: @jksoegaard each monitor is connected directly to the MBP with a separate usb-c thunderbolt 3. No docks or dongles.

Comment: What's on the other end?  DP or HDMI?  If HDMI, lose it and try DP.

Comment: The 2020 13” MBP (base model) can do 4K at 60Hz via the Thunderbolt 3 port.  More than likely, it’s your cable.  See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/327136/119271. Let me know if that has any effect.