# External display switches to lower resolution and I need to restart my MacBook to fix it

Tags: display, hdmi, resolution

My setup is the following:

- macOS Catalina, version 10.15.7 (but this has been happening since before Catalina)
- MacBook Pro (15-inch 2019)
- [AOC Q27P1](https://eu.aoc.com/en/monitors/q27p1) External display, connected via [this USB C to HDMI cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B075V5JK36/)

Display will work fine for some time, then it suddenly goes black for a couple of seconds and when it comes back on, it switches to a lower resolution for a seemingly random reason.

Here's the `Displays` settings when the bug happens:

[image]

And here's what I see after I restart the MacBook:

[image]

As you can see, the highest two resolutions disappear until I restart the MacBook. Where do you think could be the problem?

Comment: If you're using HDMI, you should use an [active adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/398441/119271) and not a cable.  However, that monitor supports DisplayPort as an input, so I would go with a [USB-C DisplayPort cable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/327136/119271)

Comment: So you think this problem is directly related to the cable I use? I will get an USB-C DisplayPort cable like you recommended to see if it fixes it. Thanks.