# External display doesn't work, keeps disappearing and reappearing in settings

Tags: display, hdmi

I am trying to connect my MacBook Pro to an external display (HP E24i G4) via HDMI. The display doesn't work. When I go to Display Settings to check on it, I see the following:

[image]

Then, in a split second, this

[image]

And so it keeps "blinking", appearing and disappearing in display settings. The display itself stays dark the whole time

The display works fine with other computers. What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press the "Settings" button on the display itself to open the settings menu. Navigate to "input". Most likely it is set to DisplayPort or something else. "Auto-Switch input" is set to True which should lead to the display auto-detecting that it needs to use HDMI, but with a Mac it leads to this weird blinking behavior. Switch to HDMI.

Comment: You will get better results if you use a native [USB-C cable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/327136/119271) either Type-C to C or Type-C to DisplayPort.  DP is the native signal so converting to [HDMI can cause issues](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/398441/119271)