# Macbook Air (2020) not sending signal to 4K monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I'm trying to use my Macbook Air (M1, 2020) with a Dell 3223q 4K monitor.  I'm plugging the mac into a charging dock via USBC which is connected to the monitor via a Display Port 1.4 cable.  This setup worked fine with my old 1440p monitor.

When I plug in I can see the monitor is recognized by the mac and shows up in System Preferences / Display, but the monitor stays black and says it does not have a signal from the Display Port.

How can I go about debugging this?

Comment: Start by bypassing the dock.  Use a quality [USB-C to DisplayPort Cable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/327136/119271).  Many can be charge only cables and lack all of the connectors for signaling.