# USB Display Device icon on menubar when I login

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, sonoma

I have a MacBook Pro M1 running Sonoma.

Every time I login, an icon associated with an application called "USB Display Device" shows up in my menubar.

[image]

When I click on Show Diagnostics, it opens the application, which looks like this

[image]

I think this may be related to the j5create hub I use, but I'm not actually connected to my external display through the hub. I'm connected to the display's HTML port directly from my second USB port, because it didn't work through the hub (I was able to use the display's DisplayPort through the hub, but it had other problems -- see my earlier question [External display backlight turns on for no reason](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/462524/external-display-backlight-turns-on-for-no-reason)). It might have started when I tried downloading a driver from the j5create website, hoping that would fix the inability to use the display through the hub.

Clicking on "Activate USB Display Driver" doesn't seem to do anything. This happens in both my regular account (which doesn't have admin privileges) and the Administrator account.

I can click on "Quit USB Display Device Tool" and there's no problem. But I wish this wouldn't appear every time if it doesn't really serve a purpose. Anyone know how I can get rid of it permanently? Should I just remove the application?

Comment: Have you updated your Mac to the proper [j5 Create drivers](https://en.j5create.com/pages/drivers#page-3) for this specific device? You say 'hub' , but j5 has many hubs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I downloaded for this device.