# MBP in Clamshell mode: display doesn't come on when waking up

Tags: display, sleep-wake, hdmi, closed-clamshell

I have an M1 Macbook Pro (2020) running Ventura. Most of the time I use it in clamshell mode.

I can easily wake it from sleep the using the external wireless keyboard (I hear the fans come on, the external drive flashes, there is a 'dong' sound when I press `Option+Cmd` - so the mac is definitely awake). But very often the display just says no signal and goes to sleep.

It is very inconvenient to take the mbp out of it's stand and open up the display to log in - which does turn the external monitor on.

The only trick that works is to unplug the power lead from the mac for several seconds and then plug it back in.

The technical details of my set up are:

1. The mac is connected to an Anker USB C hub.
2. The hub connects via HDMI to an HDMI switch (which also has an input for a Windows laptop where things work fine).
3. The HDMI switch connects to an external monitor via HDMI.

Comment: The first thing to do is get down to basics and remove the KVM (the switch) from the equation. If you plug the monitor directly into the Mac, does the problem go away?

Comment: @Allan It is not a KVM switch, just an HDMI switch. The keyboard and mouse are logitech multi-device ones. I will have go leaving out the HDMI switch and report back.

Comment: If at all possible, try to go as basic as possible, buy going from the USB-C port directly to the monitor.  If the monitor has a USB-C connection, that would be the best, second would be a [USB-C to DisplayPort cable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/327136/119271), and finally, [USB-C to HDMI Active Adapter](http://radnex.us/Trend-Net-USB-C-HDMI-Adapter).