Distortion and window sizing issue on external display, when refresh is higher than 30
I have been using this setup (Macbook Pro M2 + Philips 276E display) since at least November and haven't had a single issue with it until now. As you can see in the youtube video I've linked to below, there's a strange distortion on the screen, and the windows don't scale properly even though the secondary monitor is set to default resolution.
The issue is not with the monitor itself nor with my HDMI cables (unfortunately I don't have a display port as of right now) but with the Mac itself, as the distortion and sizing problems go away when I lower the refresh rate to 30 hz or below. The issue starts already at 50 hz. I tried upgrading to  Sonoma 14.5 but to no avail.
Is there anything I can do about it? Any help is highly appreciated.
Video: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/RBD-84DNIHY

It could be your HDMI cable because HDMI is not the native signal from your Mac - DisplayPort is.  See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/327125/119271

@Allan, I think I solved it. It seems like I had turnt on overscan on the monitor, which for some reason prompted the Mac to do whatever this was. I will be looking for a Display port eventually, though. Thank you for your response :)
